# Transformation of continuous random variables

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, statistical-inference

Let's say that $Y = \log T = \alpha + \sigma W$. I know that If $W$ has logsitic distribution, the $T$ will have the log-logistic distribution. Also, if $W$ has the standard normal distribution then $T$ has log normal distribution.

My questions are these:

What are the names of the distributions obtained if

(1) $W$ has the exponential distribution
(2) $W$ has the log normal distribution

Comment: It should not be difficult to use the standard methods for transforming distributions to get PDFs and CDFs for (1) and (2). But not every distribution has a well-known name. For (1) perhaps 'shifted exponential'. No clue for (2).

Comment: @BruceET Yes, It is not difficult. I can get the PDFs and CDFs easily. I was wondering if they have a well-known name. Thanks for your comment.